# WCF Service fails to load in Cassini with a metadata error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, metadata, mex

This is my first WCF service and I am having what seems to be a common problem for newbies i.e. the configuration file.

The service project was created with examples from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide) and after receiving the error `[Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.]`, I went through the MSDN way of Web.config [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751951.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicemetadatabehavior.aspx).

Here is my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="Parkalot.WcfClient.Services.UserService">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7349/ServiceMetadata" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address="/UserService" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Parkalot.WcfClient.Services.IUserServiceContract" />
                <!-- Adds a WS-MetadataExchange endpoint at "http://localhost:7349/ServiceMetadata/mex" -->
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="metadataSupport">
                    <!-- Enables the IMetadataExchange endpoint in services that -->
                    <!-- use "metadataSupport" in their behaviorConfiguration attribute. -->
                    <!-- In addition, the httpGetEnabled and httpGetUrl attributes publish -->
                    <!-- Service metadata for retrieval by HTTP/GET at the address -->
                    <!-- "http://localhost:8080/ServiceMetadata?wsdl" -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost:7349/ServiceMetadata?wsdl" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The error details are:

```
    Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:7349/Services/UserService.svc
If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.
For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.
WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:7349/Services/UserService.svc
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
'http://localhost:7349/Services/UserService.svc'.
The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.
HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost:7349/Services/UserService.svc
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:7349/Services/UserService.svc'.
```

I have stripped a ton of lines from the error which is probably meant to render in a browser. Since I am running from within Visual Studio, I do not have a browser context.

Comment: Well it launches the WCF Test Client and that is where this error appears. Maybe I have worded the question wrong.

Comment: Based on the links you're using, you're using the WCF Rest Starter Kit (which, by the way, is no longer supported).  The WCF Test Client doesn't understand REST.  You need to test the REST service in a browser (or via code), as shown in the two projects your linked to (and modify your web config as well).

Comment: @Tim: Thanks. What I cannot figure out is how to launch it in a browser, let alone debug it after that.

Comment: Both of the code projects you linked to show how to launch it in the browser.  Did you follow them through to the end?